# SVG miniature sizes in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, svg

Nautilus shows miniatures of SVG images but some are smaller and some are bigger. How can I adjust this, in either Nautilus or images themselves?

[image]

Comment: are those smaller .svg has the same pix size as the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the .svg files and changed the

```
width="59.056px" height="59.056px"
```

into 512px each and refreshed folder view.